# How does adding "(" ")" change the gradle warning message?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
```

is highlighted with a very typical error message, *nothing special*:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and
>   com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) .....

But when I add `(  )` around it, that warning is gone...

```
androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2')
```

- Android Studio 3.3
- `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0`

I just noticed this, never noticed if this 
occurred on previous versions. I didn't think `( )` would make a difference, or is this a lint bug?

Repro: just create any new project and add another dependency that triggers that warning, such as `com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps`, then go ahead and insert/toggle `( )` to see for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[based on what it says here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/inspecting_dependencies.html#sec:dependency_declaration_reasons) it seems like adding the `()` is meant for providing a justification for using that specific verison and can be used like so:

```
implementation('org.ow2.asm:asm:6.0') {
    because 'we require a JDK 9 compatible bytecode generator'
}
```

So the warning is likely going away because it thinks you have a good reason for using that version